# rewrite url with a #

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How do you rewrite a url with a # in? e.g. http://www.example.com/index.php#test

In my current .htaccess file I have:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine

RewriteRule  ^([^/.]+)/?$ $1.php [L] # rewrite without query string parameters
RewriteRule  ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ $1.php\#$2 [L] # one name string parameter
```

This would rewrite a url such as http://www.example.com/index/test so you are directed to the page, but not take you to the relevant  tag like http://www.example.com/index#test or http://www.example.com/index.php#test would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use something like this to redirect an url to another with a hash at the end:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$ $1.php#$2 [R=301,L,NE]
```

**Note:** The # (and anything after it) is not part of the actual HTTP request to the server.
So you can't refer to it or get the hash value in you .htaccess.

> The hash is never sent to the server, so you can't match it with
>   mod_rewrite!

You have to use e.g. Javascript to acces values after the hash!